# Android studio - Change the .gradle folder location

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-8.0-oreo

I'm currently testing Android O for my published Android application.

And my Gradle fails each time because it is looking for file in : "C:\Users\M?lanie.gradle\caches".
As you can see my name contains a problematic character and I've already move my Android sdk because of it.

**How can I move the .gradle folder too ?**

I've tried to set the "GRADLE_USER_HOME" to "C:\Android\gradle" (the folder exists) but Android Studio still behaves the same way.

Answer (score 26):

To change its path
go to this path `File > Settings... > Build, Execution, Deployment > Gradle`
In the Global Gradle settings
Change Service directory path to what you want.

Hope this works

Comment: same thing not changed with crashlyticsUploadDistributionDevRelease

Comment: You also need to set GRADLE_USER_HOME environment variable as pointed out by another answer - for me, this was a required extra step to get it to work

Answer (score 11):

Currently, to Change the `.gradle` folder location for Android Studio, you must:
Define the `GRADLE_USER_HOME` environment variable to point to *`C:\WorkFolder\.gradle`*.

You can read more in the [Configure the IDE docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config?hl=sr#custom-locations).

Comment: I've tested this environment variable on Windows and it works perfectly 